# Why can't I return an array of objects to UIStackView in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uistackview

```
import UIKit

class MenuBar: UIView{
    let buttonWidth = 50

    let friendsButton: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Friends Button")
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50)
        imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50)
        return imageView
    }()
```

creating a friends button

```
    let circleButton: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Small Circle Button")

        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50)
        imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50)
        return imageView
    }()
```

creating a circle button

```
    let profileButton: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Profile Button")
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50)
        imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50)
        return imageView
    }()
```

creating a profile button

```
    let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [profileButton, circleButton, profileButton])}
```

The last line is the line that gives me the error: cannot use instance member 'profileButton within property initializer

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Update your question with the error. And then search on the error for lots of answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important part of the error message you got is the second part which unfortunately you omitted.  It is `property initializer is initialized before self`.

The next error you'll get after rewrite without property initalizer pattern would be `Expected declaration`. That means the `code segment` need to be inside a function. Like `viewDidLoad()` for example.

Thus, for it to work, your code need to be modified to something similar to:

```
import UIKit

class MenuBar: UIView {   
    func createStackView() -> UIStackView {
        let buttonWidth = 50

        let friendsButton = UIImageView()
        friendsButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        friendsButton.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Friends Button")
        friendsButton.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        friendsButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50)
        friendsButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50)


        let circleButton = UIImageView()
        circleButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        circleButton.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Small Circle Button")

        circleButton.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        circleButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50)
        circleButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50)


        let  profileButton = UIImageView()
        profileButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        profileButton.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Profile Button")
        profileButton.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        profileButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50)
        profileButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50)

        let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [profileButton, circleButton, profileButton])
        return stackView
    }
}
```

Comment: After you confirm that it works. Please accept the answer, so I get the 15 points.  If you have other question, please write a comment.